# How to see context variable in lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I set sample lambda function as follows to detect what is `context`.
This function is hooked by API gateway.

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'isBase64Encoded': False,
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {},
        'body': json.dumps(context)
    }
```

And when I send GET request from API gateway it returned as follows

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

```
Mon May 24 07:20:58 UTC 2021 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: Object of type LambdaContext is not JSON serializable. Lambda request id: 32d4e450-576b-4bd6-abb9-d1bd893077ed
Mon May 24 07:20:58 UTC 2021 : Method completed with status: 502
```

`context` is not `json` format ? How can I see `context` in handler ?

If someone has opinion,please let me know

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html

Comment: Ooh, nice link! It looks like `context` is a class, upon which functions can be called. It isn't a data object that has values that can be serialized to JSON.

Comment: Note you can simply print the context object and it will appear in CloudWatch Logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can print it and see if you want. It would be something like this:

```
LambdaContext([aws_request_id=7d78a745-bb86-42b8-89f0-389e9bdc3dcfe,log_group_name=/aws/lambda/mldx-devops-v1-TimeLambda-hINHLpDGpaNR,log_stream_name=2022/09/01/[$LATEST]0553dabc81194a57adf2a96775f88d02,function_name=mldx-devops-v1-TimeLambda-hINHLpDGpaNR,memory_limit_in_mb=128,function_version=$LATEST,invoked_function_arn=arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:187276065257:function:mldx-devops-v1-TimeLambda-hINHLpDGpaNR,client_context=None,identity=CognitoIdentity([cognito_identity_id=None,cognito_identity_pool_id=None])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Print it with this code :)

```
def lambda_handler(event: Dict[str, Optional[Any]], context: LambdaContext) -> Dict[str, Optional[Any]]:
print(event)
print('print context variables')
print("context.function_name:", context.function_name)
print("context.function_version:", context.function_version)
print("context.invoked_function_arn:", context.invoked_function_arn)
print("context.memory_limit_in_mb", context.memory_limit_in_mb)
print("context.aws_request_id", context.aws_request_id)
print("context.log_group_name", context.log_group_name)
print("context.log_stream_name", context.log_stream_name)

print("print context.identity variables")
print("context.identity.cognito_identity_id", context.identity.cognito_identity_id)
print("context.identity.cognito_identity_pool_id", context.identity.cognito_identity_pool_id)

print("print context.client_context variables")
print("context.client_context.client.app_package_name", context.client_context.client.app_package_name)
print("context.client_context.client.app_version_name", context.client_context.client.app_version_name)
print("context.client_context.client.app_version_code", context.client_context.client.app_version_code)
print("context.client_context.client.app_title", context.client_context.client.app_title)
print("context.client_context.client.installation_id", context.client_context.client.installation_id)
print("context.client_context.custom", context.client_context.custom)
print("context.client_context.env", context.client_context.env)
```

Comment: [ERROR] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'client' on context.client_context.client.installation_id, do you know why?